# Горизонтальная линия рядом с картинкой

Tags: css, вёрстка

Нужно сделать, как на картинке:
[image]

На всём сайте очень много горизонтальных линий (нарисована красным). Они должны быть по всей ширине блока. Но, если линия оказывается рядом с картинкой (с `float:left/right`), то линия должна по ширине доходить только до картинки (+ ее `margin`). А получается так, что линия растягивается на всю ширину и заходит под картинку. Линия сделана `<div>`-ом:

```
.line {
  height:1px;
  margin:22px 0 26px 0;
  background:#c7c7c7;
  border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}
```

Если сделать `<hr>` вместо `<div>`, то линия ведёт себя нормально, но там другие проблемы, поэтому `<hr>` не подходит.
Скажите, можно ли так вообще сделать, и если можно то как?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте оборачивать изображение в `div` с указанным цветом фона и паддингами равными необходимым отступам картинки.

```
<style type="text/css">
.line {
height:1px;
margin:22px 0 26px 0;
background:#c7c7c7;
border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}
.img_wrapper {
float:left; 
padding:10px 10px 10px 0; 
background:#fff;
}
</style>

*текст*
<div class="img_wrapper"><img src="" /></div>
*текст*
<div class="line"></div>
*текст*
```

Должно помочь в условиях одноцветного фона.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.line {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  background: #c7c7c7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

b { animation: 1.5s infinite ease-in-out pulse; color: #b00; } @keyframes pulse { 50% { letter-spacing: 3px; } }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2dEX.png">
Достаточно добавить классу линии одно свойство:
<div class="line"></div>
<pre>.line {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  background: #c7c7c7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  <b>overflow: hidden;</b>
}</pre>
<div class="line"></div>
Вроде всё.
```